# Sparkjava Error: org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - Header is too large >8192

Tags: jetty, spark-java

We are developping an internal web component based on sparkjava framework, and HTTP GET is used but not POST for convenient.

An error is returned when request URL contains large data (more than 8K) as follow:
`org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - Header is too large >8192`.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sparkjava](http://sparkjava.com/) runs on an embedded Jetty server, but most of Jetty configuration is hardcode by default in sparkjava framework.

One solution is to customize EmbeddedServerFactory:

```java
    static Server server = null;

    private static void startup() {
        EmbeddedServers.add(EmbeddedServers.Identifiers.JETTY, createEmbeddedServerFactory());

        awaitInitialization();

        Stream.of(server.getConnectors()).map(Connector::getConnectionFactories).flatMap(Collection::stream)
                        .filter(t -> t.getClass().isAssignableFrom(HttpConnectionFactory.class))
                        .map(t -> ((HttpConnectionFactory) t).getHttpConfiguration()).forEach(t -> {
                            t.setRequestHeaderSize(512 * 1024 * 1024);
                            t.setSendServerVersion(false);
                            t.setSendDateHeader(false);
                        });
    }

    private static EmbeddedServerFactory createEmbeddedServerFactory() {
        return new EmbeddedJettyFactory(new JettyServerFactory() {
            @Override
            public Server create(int maxThreads, int minThreads, int threadTimeoutMillis) {
                return create(maxThreads <= 0 ? null
                                : new QueuedThreadPool(maxThreads, minThreads, threadTimeoutMillis));
            }

            @Override
            public Server create(ThreadPool threadPool) {
                return server = new Server(threadPool);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: That is an excessively large header size configuration, and you are now subject to various old CVEs related to header collisions that the default limit protects against.  It would be trivial for a user to issue 1 request, cause 100% CPU until connection idle timeout with that configuration. - See https://ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html

Comment: If you are using URI query excessively, consider switching to POST body forms instead.    If you are using large headers (over 4k in size), such as `Cookie`, then know that your application will only work with custom clients.  Most browsers, and many proxies, will not support that excessive of a request.